# SDN4 - Repository query not hitting the database and returning stale data on load after delete operation

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

One of my unit tests seems to be returning stale data. The test is testing whether I can delete some ticket types from an event (that tickets are sold for). I've left comments to show what is going wrong in the code.

```
            @Test
            public void deleteTicketTypeByDomainSpecificId() { 
                logger.info("Given we have a member with an event that has some ticket types");
                Member member = createMember();
                Event event = eventService.createEvent("My cool new event", member);
                String eventId = event.getDomainSpecificId();

                // create our first ticket type
                TicketTypeCreator ticketTypeCreator = ticketTypeService.new TicketTypeCreator();
                ticketTypeCreator.setUiId(UniqueIDGenerator.randomID());
                ticketTypeCreator.setTicketTypeName("Seated ticket");
                ticketTypeCreator.setTicketTypeUrl("http://www.joesevents.com/joe");
                ticketTypeCreator.setTicketTypePrice("58.00");
                ticketTypeCreator.setEvent(event);
                TicketType ticketType1 = ticketTypeCreator.create();
```

// one ticket type can be seen at this point on localhost:7474 (what we expect)

```
                // create our second ticket type
                ticketTypeCreator.setUiId(UniqueIDGenerator.randomID());
                ticketTypeCreator.setTicketTypeName("Standing ticket");
                ticketTypeCreator.setTicketTypeUrl("http://www.jillsevents.com");
                ticketTypeCreator.setTicketTypePrice("38.00");
                ticketTypeCreator.setEvent(event);
                ticketTypeCreator.create();
```

// two ticket types can be seen at this point on localhost:7474 (what we expect)

```
                logger.info("When we delete a ticketType");
                ticketTypeService.deleteTicketTypeByDomainSpecificId(ticketType1.getDomainSpecificId());
```

// one ticket type can be seen at this point on localhost:7474 (what we expect)

```
                // This code loads only one ticket type which is what we expect
                Iterable<TicketType> ticketTypes = ticketTypeService.findAll();
                int count = 0;
                for (TicketType ticketType : ticketTypes) { 
                    count ++;
                }
                assertThat(count, is(equalTo(1)));

                logger.info("And the event should have one less ticket type type after we reload it");
```

**// This code loads two ticket types even though the database on port 7474 is showing 1 ticket type and even though the previous code only returned 1 ticket type.**

```
                event = eventService.loadEventByDomainSpecificId(eventId);
                Set<TicketType> ticketTypes2 = event.getTicketTypes();
                for (TicketType ticketType : ticketTypes2) { 
                    System.out.println(ticketType.getTicketTypeName());
                }
                assertThat(event.getTicketTypes().size(), is(equalTo(1)));
            }
```

eventService.loadEventByDomainSpecificId(eventId) is a @Service that simply calls a repository shown below. There is no caching done by the service.

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends GraphRepository<Event>{

    public Event findByDomainSpecificId(String domainSpecificId);

}
```

Comment: is there an implementation of EvenRepository's findByDomainSpecificId(...) method? if yes can you post it? Maybe it has something to do with custom repository methods outside the GraphRepository interface

Comment: Also how are neo4j sessions utilized in your test? It sounds like caching is going on but in the docs they explicitly say the session does not cache entities. However, the point of 'stale' entities and their possible causes is addressed in the docs. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_session_bean

Comment: What does deleteTicketTypeByDomainSpecificId look like? Can you re-try this with the latest OGM snapshot (1.1.4-SNAPSHOT)?